# Bootstrap nav items not appearing in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a frustrating issue with bootstrap's mobile navigation. The issue is that the menu items are not appearing after clicking the button for display. I've tried several fixes on two different phones with no result.

The first fix was adding the below code as mentioned on http://alittlecode.com/fix-twitter-bootstraps-dropdown-menus-in-touch-screens/ though this is for version 2.3.2. I also used the previous code with no results.

```
      $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
           $(this).siblings('.dropdown-backdrop').off().remove();
         }
        }, this), 0);
      });
```

The second effort was removing

```
    if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
      $('<div class="dropdown-backdrop"/>').insertAfter($(this)).on('click', clearMenus)
    }
```

From the bootstrap minified js doc.

The code for the navbar itself is below, the main edit being the removal of the container though it didn't work even with the container present. I can't figure this out for the life of me, your help is appreciated.

> ```
>                     <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
>                         <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
>                         <div class="navbar-header">
>                           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-toggle">
>                             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
>                             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>                             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>                             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>                           </button>
>                         </div>
>                         <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
>                         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation-toggle">
>                           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
>                             <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
>                             <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
>                             <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
>                             <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
>                           </ul>
>                         </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
>                     </nav>
> ```

Comment: Just copy the code from [Bootstrap Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) and then make sure you are linking to bootstrap's dependencies `jQuery` and `bootstrap.min.js`.

Comment: try to replace line `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation-toggle">` with `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">`

Comment: @Rafael as mentioned below, the original unedited navbar works, but when I remove all links except those with the class `navbar-right` this issue is present.

Comment: @Banzay the id, as well as the data-target have been updated, even with the original title the effect is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Forget other manual fixing because bootstrap have it own. Just simply call **JS_FILE_PATH/bootstrap.min.js** after calling any standard jQuery version. Remember bootstrap.min.js will not work if you do not call jquery before it.

I hope this'll solve your issue. I tried this on my own.

Comment: This did not solve the issue, however it works with the original from getbootstrap.com, the issue only comes into effect when I remove all links except those set with the class `navbar-right`.